# JMeter: Application of Pre-Processor and Post-Processor

Tags: post, hyperlink, jmeter, preprocessor, post-processor

I would like to know the Application of Pre-Processor and Post-Processor in JMeter.

Comment: Application means usage or their architecture?

Comment: Means where can I use these things with practical example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As name suggests these components are used to process something (request, response, custom operations) before and after the sampler (request).

**Pre processors** :

These components are used before the request to perform custom actions.

Ex:
Suppose If I want to add something to request before sending it to server then preprocessor is added. For example if could be fetching some information from DB or Regex operations. Thus after performing those operation we can pass results of these actions to request. Thus we can modify/update request or request parameters before sending request to server.

**Post processors** : 
These components are used after the response of request has arrived to perform custom actions.

Ex:
Suppose If I have asked for something on google and I want to find out something from response for below actions,

1. To validate response
2. Extract something and process to pass data to next request
3. Perform custom actions like DB operations, file operations etc.

Then post processors can be used.

See above snapshot,
[image]

Components pointed by arrow will be executed before request is sent to server and components within square will be executed after response has arrived.

I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Pre Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors) are designed to provide any setup actions required for the test sample like generate some unique test data or amend parent sampler dynamically

[Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) are designed to tear down the sampler, or most commonly to extract "interesting" bits from response for later re-use (this is called "correlation")

Pre and Post Processors execution time isn't included into test reports. If you want to change this behavior you need to use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller)